# high_voltage double URL routing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, high-voltage

I'm getting the following error when I routing in my app

> Routing Error
>
> No such page: pages/contact

The page does exist, I've noticed in the URL it says:

http://localhost:3000/pages/pages/contact So rendering double /pages/

Routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'pages/index' => 'high_voltage/pages#show', id: 'index'
  root :to => 'high_voltage/pages#show', id: 'index'
end
```

html.erb

```
<%= link_to 'pages/contact', :class => 'btn btn--sm btn--primary type--uppercase' do %>
```

It's important to note if I'm routing from index -> contact it's fine, however, if I route from another internal page such as about or team, it will double render in the URL

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the default rails routing system for High_voltage 
 Default rails is:

```
    <%= link_to 'Privacy Policy', 'pages/about' %>
```

When the proper routing for high_voltage is:

```
    <%= link_to 'About', page_path('about') %>
```

If i was already on localhost:3000/pages/about/ it'd try and render pages again as specified in the default rails link_to versus the high_voltage